# A changing probability relating to primes

Tags: probability, statistics, prime-numbers

The probability that a process succeeds at step $t$ is

$$\left( \prod_{k=1}^{t-1}{ 1-\text{Prime}(p+k)^{-1/c} } \right)(\text{Prime}(p+t))^{-1/c}$$

Here $p$, $t$ and $c$ are naturals, and $\text{Prime}(x)$ is simply the $x$th prime.

How many steps, on average, does the proccess take until it succeeds, for a given $p$ and $c$?

**MY ATTEMPTS**

The first thing I *tried* was to try to convert the prime in the function to a power of $x$, hoping that I could test it in my math software and get close to the same asymptotics:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{t-1}{ \left(1-(\text{Prime}(p)^{d \cdot k})^{-1/c} \right) }\text{Prime}(p+t)$$

The idea was to approximate $\text{Prime}(p+k)$ with $x^{d \cdot  k}$ for $d \approx 1$, say $d=1.1$.  But by my calculations, this wasn't exacting enough.  Perhaps I have to rethink $d$.

That was probably my best attempt so far.  I'm still thinking that maybe we can approximate the prime values with a power of $x$, or some suitable function.  I'm not sure what else to try.  I feel like I'm way off here.

Anyways, the idea seems to be to get the product equal to around $1/2$, which would be an average number of steps or trials.

Comment: The first expression is the probability of success for that individual step assuming previous steps failed, or the overall probability that previous steps failed and then step $t$ succeeds?

Comment: @aschepler: The second one, I think (these sum to $1$).

Comment: @aschepler:  The fist expression is the overall probability that the previous steps failed and then step $t$ succeeds...  metamorphy is correct.

Comment: Instead of $\mathrm{Prime}(p+k) \approx x^{dk}$, maybe [$\mathrm{Prime}(n) \approx n \ln n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) would get somewhere?

Comment: @metamorphy:  Actually, this has applications, assuming that my math is correct...  I can get back to you after the (probably months long) process of checking my work, if you'd like.  The problem for me has always been trying to determine the average time to succeed.  Without this, the result is not as interesting.

Answer (score 1):

1. For a r.v. $X$ on $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ with $\mathbb{P}(X=n)=p_n$, the expected value is $\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}np_n$ (of course).
2. If $p_n=q_n-q_{n+1}$, where $1=q_1>q_2>q_3>\ldots$ and $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_n$ converges, then $\mathbb{E}X=S$.
3. Now let $a_n\in(0,1)$ with $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-a_n)=0$. If we put $q_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-a_k)$, assuming $q_1=1$, then $p_n[{}=a_n q_n]$ has the needed form. With $a_k=\text{Prime}(p+k)^{-1/c}$, $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)=0$ *does* hold.
4. In the case $c>1$, $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_n$ converges. This is shown using $1-a_n<e^{-a_n}$ and estimating $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ from below, using $a_n\sim(n\log n)^{-1/c}$; it grows at least as fast as $N^a$ for any $a<1-1/c$, which is sufficient. Thus, the answer is $S$. It doesn't have a closed form - you have to leave it as is.
5. Finally, suppose $c=1$. Then, from [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems), $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n\log n$ exists and is positive. Together with $a_n\sim(n\log n)^{-1}$, this easily implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}np_n$ diverges. Thus, the answer is $\infty$.