# The chance of eventual success, with a function over primes.

Tags: probability, statistics, prime-numbers

A process is done as a sequence of trials.  If the $k$th trial succeeds with probability

$$\frac{1}{\text{Prime}(p+k)}$$

and fails with probability

$$1 - \frac{1}{\text{Prime}(p+k)}$$

with $p$ a given natural number, what is the probability that it will succeed for one or more trials?

This is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643727/a-changing-probability-relating-to-primes), but ultimately different.  The formulas are not the same, and here I am looking for the probability that there is at least one success (which is not $1$), whereas there one success is guaranteed.

---

**MY ATTEMPTS**

It's fairly easy to show that the sum over all $k$ is

$$1 - \frac{ \displaystyle \prod_k{ \left( \text{Prime}(p + k) - 1 \right) } }{ \displaystyle \prod_k{ \text{Prime}(p + k) } }$$

My problem is where to proceed from here.  I think that it would be best to try some probabilistic approach, but I don't know how.

Instead, I tried rewriting the products as sums, via the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_product#Connection_to_indefinite_sum):

$$\prod_x{f(x)} = e^{ \displaystyle\sum_x{\log{f(x)}} }$$

From there, I intended to approximate the summation via [Euler-Maclaurin summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), but the problem I basically have is to get a good series representation for the integral.  Plus, every series that I did get needs a lot of terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of failure

$$
\prod_{p\gt p_n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)
$$

(where I’ve replaced your slightly idiosyncratic $p$ by $n$ to have $p$ free for its conventional use as a prime) diverges to $0$ (see [Mertens’ third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#In_number_theory)), so there will [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) be at least one success. In fact, the [second Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) implies that there will almost surely be infinitely many successes.

Comment: I probably should have picked that up from the previous question I asked.  Anyways, thanks for making it obvious...  That was much simpler than my approach!